# DownloadManager VS Own download implementation?

Tags: android, download, download-manager

I'm building an application in which I need to download large files.

The application needs to support:
-Download big files (off course..)
-Resume broken downloads
-Be notified about download progress
-Download in the background (when user isn't in the app)
-Manualy pause/resume of downloads

Should I use Android's DownloadManager or implement my own download manager?

thanks in advance!

Comment: You were doing exactly what I need to do now. I'm not sure to use DownloadManager or write my own service. Did you find your answer now? If yes, please share your implementation. Thank you!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Well I finally Implemented my own download manager, As it is best way to make it flexible to my needs.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is much easier and probably less error-prone to go with the Android DownloadManager. Be aware though, that it needs Android 2.3 (not so much of a problem anymore I should think).

Comment: Much a problem anymore. My device has Android 2.2 and it has not even 2 years, a child age for a phone.

Comment: mine is 2.2 also, the only reason I support that version in my app, otherwise I would think hard whether the 3% of users are worth the hassle, but that depends strongly on the targeted demographic and the type of app.